# What is blocking my query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a very interesting situation in SqlServer: I cannot find the process blocking another process.
I run the following select:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE blocked > 0
```

There I receive a single row containing the value "58" in blocked.
Thus I send the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = 58
```

And I get nothing!
How is this possible?

I am using Sqlserver 2008 R2

Comment: try with 

EXEC sp_who2
GO

Comment: No "58" in there either...

Comment: Plz share the table structure.

Comment: This is a data-model with about 50 tables. What kind of information would help you? The question above deals only with system tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
SELECT db.name                  DBName,
       tl.request_session_id,
       wt.blocking_session_id,
       OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) BlockedObjectName,
       tl.resource_type,
       h1.TEXT                  AS RequestingText,
       h2.TEXT                  AS BlockingTest,
       tl.request_mode
FROM   sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl
       INNER JOIN sys.databases db
               ON db.database_id = tl.resource_database_id
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS wt
               ON tl.lock_owner_address = wt.resource_address
       INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
               ON p.hobt_id = tl.resource_associated_entity_id
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec1
               ON ec1.session_id = tl.request_session_id
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec2
               ON ec2.session_id = wt.blocking_session_id
       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec1.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h1
       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec2.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h2
```

This will give you list of blocking sessions.

Use this command to kill the session.

```
Kill sessionid
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
EXECUTE sp_who2 GO
```

You may need to get some higher permissions or have your platform team run it though, as it is a system stored procedure.